# When closing as a duplicate, is it OK to link to the entry which is itself closed as a duplicate?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions

When closing as a duplicate, is it OK to link to the entry which is itself closed as a duplicate of another, older entry with much higher views count (2k vs 170 views), and more answers which are also much more upvoted (and also are more comprehensive)?

Should I edit the list and re-link it to the older, non-closed, (arguably) more valuable entry?

Case in point: [Non-exhaustive pattern matching?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69197294/non-exhaustive-pattern-matching)

I feel this my question is probably a duplicate itself, but none of the questions suggested by the SO engine when I wrote it seemed applicable.

Comment: Feel free to chose whatever is "best suited" on a case-by-casee basis - it might be that the interim target will be useful for the OP to gain some perspective. On the other hand, you are creating a chain of linked posts which some find a bit frustrating to follow (there are some egregious examples here on Meta that involve up to half a dozen "rings" in the chain). So... just use your best judgement :)

Comment: @OlegValter not me, someone else did it. I wonder whether I must intervene and link directly to the older target or it is OK to leave it as it is.

Comment: You could always edit the duplicates and add the other as well. A question can be a duplicate of more than one other question.

Comment: @Larnu that's a good suggestion, a compromise. still I'd like also to have an authoritative verdict whether such linking to closed Q is at all acceptable.

Comment: @WillNess "you" was a generic you, not you personally :) Methinks "up to you" will be the predominant response - both approaches look fine. Just strive towards closing to the best of possible dupe targets, and you should be all good. In any case, the mere act of dupe closure is a service to the community (unless done in good faith - look no further than the [tag:regex] for an example of the contrary)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's really up to your judgement. If you have the dupehammer you can decide whether to change the duplicate target for a more suited one, add it as a second one or leave it as it is. Sometimes another duplicate question has a context that suits the new question better. Sometimes the answer is geared more towards the specific example posted by the question asker. You need to decide which question you want to direct people to.

Ideally, we would like to have a single question with all the best answers. That's not always possible. There are different circumstances that lead to the same problem. This is why we have duplicates so that they might act as signposts. Even if there's a chain of duplicate links, the last one should be the best one. People who land on one of the less-visited ones can then navigate to the canonical.

Comment: thanks for this. in the mean time I've edited the dupe list there to add the older original, without removing the interim one. It just seems weird when someone closes a Q as a dupe of another which is itself already closed as a dupe... by that same closer. :) I guess this is not prohibited then.